# Vector2.Reflect not reflecting as it should

Tags: unity-game-engine, linear-algebra

I have a ball moving like this:

```
      ⚽
    ⭩ 
|‾‾‾‾‾‾|
```

Let's suppose its velocity is (-1, -1). When it collides with the ground, its velocity should be (-1,1), since it will keep going left but it will start going up (considering gravity is not necessary).

The normal vector of the collision is (0,1).

What happens is when I use `Vector2.Reflect(velocity, normal)`, instead of returning (-1,1), it returns (1, -1).

```
What I want              What it returns

       ⚽                           ⚽  
    ⭦⭩                            ⭩
 |‾‾‾‾‾‾|                      |‾‾‾‾‾‾|
                                    ⭨
```

Seems like it's reflecting over the normal vector (1,0), but it is not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PS: I've just solved it by rotating the normal vector 90º, but it seems like a workaround.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129573/unity-how-to-use-vector2-reflect
look it

Comment: I did exactly what the answers in the link say, the only difference is that the inDirection in my code is `collision.relativeVelocity`, where `collision` is the parameter of `OnCollisionEnter2D`, but I'm pretty sure this is not the problem.

Comment: Do you print ` collision.relativeVelocity ` , What is this value?

Comment: I'm guessing that the coordinate system you assume and the coordinate system being used aren't the same. For example, when you say, *`Let's suppose its velocity is (-1, -1)`* is that actually true in Unity, or did you just assume those values?

Comment: @TimChang the relativeVelocity is exactly what I said: (-1,-1). I'm supposing (-1,-1) but in Unity the real velocity is like (-0.5, -0.7).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]